# Do I need TCP port open on my DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm getting this warning from DNSstuff:

> TCP allowed
>
> Not all nameservers responded to queries via TCP. This means that queries that require TCP connections will get inconsistent answers, which can cause delays or intermittent failures. The nameservers that failed TCP queries are:

I open port 53 do I need another port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DNS is only on one port. If you've opened it, be sure you've opened both UDP and TCP, and that the DNS server software is listening on both. It is possible your DNS software has TCP turned off, which will need to be turned on.